# Adding pre_build command to add_jar cmake

Tags: jar, cmake

I'm trying to add a pre_build command to my jar in CMake. Apparently add_jar does not support this options. Is there any way to do something similar?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_command.html), *PRE_BUILD* option for `add_custom_command` is supported only in Visual Studio, for other this is equal to *PRE_LINK*. But *PRE_LINK* cannot be used for custom targets (non-library and non-executable), like `add_jar` creates. `Is there any way to do something similar?` - "something similar" is too vague... Can you provide an example where you need this feature?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I wanted to generate some java files first then add it to my jar. I was able to solve the issue.

Comment: So your question post describes [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): *PRE_BUILD* is not used for source files generation, your answer describes proper way for doing this.

Comment: I asked is there a general work around for that problem. I disagree with that statement: "PRE_BUILD is not used for source files generation", but it is not part of the topic . 
I appreciate your help, and I will be more careful with this XY problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I just had to use the output param at add_custom_command. Basically I wanted to generate some java file and add it to my jar. Here's the steps what I've done:

```
add_library(MyLib ${SRC})

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${PATH}/${file}.java"
    COMMAND ${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools/22.0.1/aidl "${PATH}/${file}.aidl" "${PATH}/${file}.java"
)

add_jar(MyLib_java
        SOURCES ${JAVA_SRC} "${PATH}/${file}.java"
        OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
        )

add_dependencies(MyLib_java MyLib)
```